# Chrome Extension - Load included HTML-file from JavaScript using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a chrome extension to modify the HTML of a page, but I can't seem to get it to work. I have four files:

manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Agor.aio h3cks scrubz lel",
  "description": "Dis sextenzion iz wery guud",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "page": "test.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
     {
       "matches": ["http://agar.io/*"],
       "js": ["contentscript.js"],
       "run_at": "document_end"
     }
   ],
    "web_accessible_resources": ["script.js", "test.html"]
}
```

contentscript.js:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('script.js');
s.onload = function() {
this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
};
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
```

script.js:

```
$('#overlays').load('test.html');

var changeRegion = function(region) {
  if(region === "Other") {
    $('#changeip').toggle();
  } else {
    setRegion(region);
  }
}

var changeIP = function(ip){
  try {
    connect("ws://" + ip);
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
    setRegion(document.getElementById('region').value);
  }
}

var playGame = function(nick) {
  setNick(nick);
  setShowMass(true);
}
```

I don't know how to load the test.html file from within the script.js. All help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Your test.html page is already running in background. You can access it with. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getBackgroundPage

Comment: Yeah. But then I would have to access it from within the contentscript.js. But I need to access it from within the script.js-file...

Comment: Don't you have access to `chrome.extension` from `script.js` ? Seems like you do...

Comment: No, i don't have access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access web-accessible resources with a url like chrome:///test.html.

If you don't know it, the id of your extensions can be found in the chrome://extensions tab.  Just put it into developer mode, and the extensions id will show up under each extension.  This id doesn't change, it's tied to the key you generated in your pem file.

Comment: Thank you! The solution was to use the extension-id in a context like this:

chrome-extension://<id>/test.html